# Wordpress theme doesn't see js files

Tags: wordpress

I created my own standalone WP theme, but the site didn't see the scripts, so I wrote it this way

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/fullpage.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/main.js"></script>
```

and now it works but I don't like how this part of code looks like. Is there any way to make scripts visible for index.php file?

Comment: go with "enqueue scripts and styles" in wordpress, you will find lot of tutorials

Comment: do I need to remove all code above from index.php in this case ?

Comment: yes...remove from index.php and add enqueue code in functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove the script code from index.php and Add enqueue code in functions.php

Try this function,

```html
function add_theme_scripts() {
    // Enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script('script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/fullpage.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/all.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

Thanks!!

Comment: But I don't have header.php in my theme, my theme has only index.php file. Do I need to add header.php in my theme to make it work?

Comment: yes, you can create the header.php file and put the starting header section code on header.php file. Also, you use wp_head() function on header.php file. So, Please follow the default wordpress theme. you can get the more idea for theme structure.

Comment: There are some problem with jQuery `GET http://gopay.su/wp-content/themes/gopay_theme/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=4.9.8 404 (Not Found)` it added `ver=4.9.8` here, how to make it work?

Comment: please check the edit comment code and try to solve it.

Comment: Your code adds `?ver=4.9.8` to all scripts and no one script works.

Comment: If it's possible then you can share your theme structure. so I can guide you

Comment: No, thanks, I figured it out and added my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

for example i have a javascript file in my child theme folder so i am using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() to look there for the path.

```
function add_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script');
```

basically i am just adding this script in my functions.php file

Answer (score -1):

I used @Priyanka Modi's answer but a bit edited. My working code is below

```
<?php   
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script('jquery-3.3.1.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');
    wp_register_script('bootstrap.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_register_script('fullpage.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/fullpage.min.js');
    wp_register_script('all.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/all.min.js');
    wp_register_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/main.js');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-3.3.1.min');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min');
    wp_enqueue_script('fullpage.min');
    wp_enqueue_script('all.min');
    wp_enqueue_script('main');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```